# Two colum left layout doesn't work properly

Tags: css, layout

I'm experimenting about css. I was building a kind of two column layout using left property but I'm in troubles. I don't understand because the content of right column (the div.right) when I scale down the page goes down. Where am I wrong?

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

.sinistra {
  float: left;
  width: 47%;
  margin: 1.5%;
  margin-right: 0%;
  padding-right: 1.4%;
  text-align: justify;
  border-right: thin dotted;
  height: 90%;
}

.destra {
  float: right;
  width: 47%;
  margin: 1.5%;
  text-align: justify;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  height: 90%;
}

.piede {
  background-color: grey;
}

.fix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="fix">
  <div class="sinistra">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cum omnium accumsan at, usu accusam legendos consequat at. Feugait tractatos adipiscing nam ad. Ius no oratio deseruisse, nec quaestio repudiare argumentum ne. Cu erant essent sed. Usu facete invenire argumentum ex, ut sint
    brute discere his. Enim veri praesent at sea, vis ex utroque detraxit partiendo. Ex est suscipiantur voluptatibus. An has rebum offendit. Mei ut ocurreret laboramus, quas aperiam ponderum ut vix. Alterum nonumes et pri. Te agam incorrupte mea, ei
    eum utroque efficiendi. Sit mundi dolorem detraxit ea, ea vel quem principes. Ad volutpat sadipscing quo, labore maiorum ex eos. Per solum omnium graecis in, ea sea iisque commodo. Ne invidunt sapientem duo, sit ex stet clita luptatum. Errem diceret
    constituam id pro. No usu recusabo voluptaria. Mei mollis docendi convenire ut, mel cu cibo appareat evertitur.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cum omnium accumsan at, usu accusam legendos consequat at. Feugait tractatos adipiscing nam ad. Ius no oratio
    deseruisse, nec quaestio repudiare argumentum ne. Cu erant essent sed. Usu facete invenire argumentum ex, ut sint brute discere his. Enim veri praesent at sea, vis ex utroque detraxit partiendo. Ex est suscipiantur voluptatibus. An has rebum offendit.
    Mei ut ocurreret laboramus, quas aperiam ponderum ut vix. Alterum nonumes et pri. Te agam incorrupte mea, ei eum utroque efficiendi. Sit mundi dolorem detraxit ea, ea vel quem principes. Ad volutpat sadipscing quo, labore maiorum ex eos. Per solum
    omnium graecis in, ea sea iisque commodo. Ne invidunt sapientem duo, sit ex stet clita luptatum. Errem diceret constituam id pro. No usu recusabo voluptaria. Mei mollis docendi convenire ut, mel cu cibo appareat evertitur. Ius aperiri gloriatur ne,
    est ei quaestio pertinacia disputationi, cum eu omnis delectus antiopam.…</div>
  <div class="destra">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cum omnium accumsan at, usu accusam legendos consequat at. Feugait tractatos adipiscing nam ad. Ius no oratio deseruisse, nec quaestio repudiare argumentum ne. Cu erant essent sed. Usu facete invenire argumentum ex, ut sint
    brute discere his. Enim veri praesent at sea, vis ex utroque detraxit partiendo. Ex est suscipiantur voluptatibus. An has rebum offendit. Mei ut ocurreret laboramus, quas aperiam ponderum ut vix. Alterum nonumes et pri. Te agam incorrupte mea, ei
    eum utroque efficiendi. Sit mundi dolorem detraxit ea, ea vel quem principes. Ad volutpat sadipscing quo, labore maiorum ex eos. Per solum omnium graecis in, ea sea iisque commodo. Ne invidunt sapientem duo, sit ex stet clita luptatum. Errem diceret
    constituam id pro. No usu recusabo voluptaria. Mei mollis docendi convenire ut, mel cu cibo appareat evertitur.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cum omnium accumsan at, usu accusam legendos consequat at. Feugait tractatos adipiscing nam ad. </div>
</div>


<div class="piede">Piede</div>
```

[Code on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3du0xq1e/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using `box-sizing:border-box` on `.sinistra`and adjust your widths to compensate for the thickness of the border and change the padding on `.sinstra` to 1.5%.

```
.sinistra {
float: left;
width: 48.5%;
margin: 1.5%;
margin-right: 0%;
padding-right: 1.5%;
text-align: justify;
border-right: thin dotted;
height: 90%;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

}

More reading: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: I knew how box-sizing works and your solution  works. But I'm not able to understand because my previous code doesn't work, what does it happen behind the hood?

Comment: If I understand correctly you are allowing 0.1% for the border. `border-width:thin` is actually measured in pixels according to this link: https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/pixel-equivelant-of-border-width-thin-medium-thick/4225 its 2px. When 0.1% in pixels is less than 2px it will wrap.

Comment: #Clinton Schram  ok but I excpected display an horizontal overflow instead  it wrap. But now I understood that float elements if they haven't enough space wrap.

Answer (score 0):

Add `box-sizing: border-box;` inside your code, like this it will be best:

```
body * {
box-sizing: border-box;
}
```